# Paramiko-expect , timing out

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to perform an automated backup procedure and everything is working fine until I try to use expect on this line `interact.expect("Enter choice (1-10) or q to quit: ")`. The error I am getting is `raise socket.timeout()` and is caused I think by that string in `expect` not being correct although if i log in manually and enter I copy the exact from the shell? Anyone know a fix around this? Thanks!

```
import paramiko
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction
def backup():

# will match root user prompt
    root_prompt = '.*# '

# will match Password: or password:
    pass_prompt = '.*assword: '


    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys() 
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 

        client.connect(hostname=server, username=user, password=pass)




    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print("Authentication failed, please verify your credentials: %s")
    except paramiko.SSHException as sshException:
        print("Unable to establish SSH connection: %s" % sshException)
    except paramiko.BadHostKeyException as badHostKeyException:
        print("Unable to verify server's host key: %s" % badHostKeyException)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)

    with SSHClientInteraction(client,timeout=10,display=True) as interact: 

        interact.send('su')
        interact.expect(pass_prompt)

        interact.send("pass")
        interact.expect(root_prompt)

        interact.send("BackupMenu")#displays specific menu for backup but menu is not using shell specific commands
        interact.expect("Enter choice (1-10) or q to quit: ")

        cmd_output_ls = interact.current_output_clean


        print cmd_output_ls


    client.close()
```

Comment: You cannot edit your question to show a correct code. It's not a question anymore. - I'm reverting the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code above to a solution that works. I changed `interact.expect("Enter choice (1-10) or q to quit: ")` to `'.*: '`.

Comment: The problem was probably that round-brackets have a special meaning in a regular expression. You have to escape them with a backslash to use literal brackets.

Comment: After I completed the backup it will go to `root_prompt` but keeps timing out. The only solution was to expect the line before the prompt but this doesn't let me enter `exit` or even another command to test if command has been complete. Can you `expect` twice?